# install AVG free edition into Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: linux, yum, 32bit, aws

I was trying to install AVG free edition into Amazon Linux AMI. It looks like it installed, but I could not start the any avg service.

The command I used to install AVG is

```
sudo yum install avg2013flx-r3118-a6926.i386.rpm
```

I also installed glibc by this command

```
sudo yum install glibc.i686
```

When I install AVG I got this warning message

```
    Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
    Examining avg2013flx-r3118-a6926.i386.rpm: avg2013flx-r3118-a6926.i386
    Marking avg2013flx-r3118-a6926.i386.rpm to be installed
    Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package avg2013flx.i386 0:r3118-a6926 will be installed
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution

    Dependencies Resolved

    =================================================================================================
     Package            Arch         Version              Repository                            Size
    =================================================================================================
    Installing:
     avg2013flx         i386         r3118-a6926          /avg2013flx-r3118-a6926.i386         168 M

    Transaction Summary
    =================================================================================================
    Install  1 Package

    Total size: 168 M
    Installed size: 168 M
    Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
    Downloading packages:
    Running transaction check
    Running transaction test
    Transaction test succeeded
    Running transaction
      Installing : avg2013flx-r3118-a6926.i386                                                   1/1 
    Installing 'avgd' service initscripts...
    Automatic installation of initscripts for your platform/distro is not supported.
    Please, in directory according to your plartform/distribution
    create symbolic link 'avgd' to initscript for AVG daemon
    /opt/avg/av/etc/init.d//avgd.all.
    Registering 'avgd' service to runlevels...
    Automatic registration of initscripts for your platform/distro is not supported.
    Please, register the 'avgd' service initscript for startup and runlevels.
    Please do configuration with /opt/avg/av/bin/avgsetup
    Generating unique user id
    Processing command line ...
    Cfg file not specified using /opt/avg/av/cfg/diagcfg.xml.
    New installation ID succesffully generated.
    Starting AVG AV
    /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.jbNRpS: line 63: /etc/init.d/avgd: No such file or directory
   warning: %post(avg2013flx-r3118-a6926.i386) scriptlet failed, exit status 127
   Non-fatalblinkOSTIN scriptlet failure in rpm package avg2013flx-r3118-a6926.i386
      Verifying  : avg2013flx-r3118-a6926.i386                                                   1/1 

    Installed:
      avg2013flx.i386 0:r3118-a6926                                                                  

    Complete!
```

when I try to update AVG by

```
sudo /opt/avg/av/bin/avgupdate
```

I got this error

```
/opt/avg/av/bin/avgupdate: error while loading shared libraries: libdialog.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Anyone know how to fix this problem.

I have no problem with ubuntu but redhat is pain

Answer (score 0):

The hint during installation is pretty clear, no?

```
Automatic installation of initscripts for your platform/distro is not supported.
    Please, in directory according to your plartform/distribution
    create symbolic link 'avgd' to initscript for AVG daemon
    /opt/avg/av/etc/init.d//avgd.all.
    Registering 'avgd' service to runlevels...
    Automatic registration of initscripts for your platform/distro is not supported.
    Please, register the 'avgd' service initscript for startup and runlevels.
    Please do configuration with /opt/avg/av/bin/avgsetup
```

So create the symlinks for the initscript:

```
cd /etc/init.d
ln -s /opt/avg/av/etc/init.d/avgd.all avgd.all
```

then you can start the service with

```
/etc/init.d/avgd.all start
```

and to enable it to start at boot automatically:

```
/sbin/chkconfig avgd.all on
```

For the missing library indicated by

> /opt/avg/av/bin/avgupdate: error while loading shared libraries:
>   **libdialog.so**: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

Try to find in which package it is contained via `yum whatprovides */libdialog.so` and install the package it finds.

Then you should probably follow the last hint:

> Please do configuration with /opt/avg/av/bin/avgsetup